# NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChanged not being called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm not getting the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChanged notification when inserting or changing objects. The context has a parent context, could this be a problem? I have no problems getting notifications on the parent context.

This is how I create the child context:

```
func createPrivateContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{
    let privateManagedObject = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateManagedObject.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext
    privateManagedObject.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy
    return privateManagedObject
}
```

This is how I add the observer to the notification center:

```
self.privateMOC = appDelegate.createPrivateContext()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "objectsDidChanged:", name: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification, object: self.privateMOC!)
```

How I insert a new object on the child context:

```
let privateMoc = getPrivateMoc()
let newTask = Task.createNewTaskInManagedObjectContext(privateMoc)
try! privateMoc.obtainPermanentIDsForObjects([newTask])
```

Expected to be notify that the object was inserted, but I never get the notification.

UPDATE:
When changing the child MOC from PrivateConcurrencyType to MainQueueConcurrencyType the notification does work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the thread where the objects where being modified. If the child context was created with a PrivateConcurrencyType, it is necessary to change the objects inside a perform block of the child context.

```
privateMOC?.performBlock({ () -> Void in
    let newTask = Task.createNewTaskInManagedObjectContext(privateMoc)
    print(newTask.objectID.URIRepresentation().absoluteString)
    try! privateMoc.obtainPermanentIDsForObjects([newTask])
    print(newTask.objectID.URIRepresentation().absoluteString)
})
```

Comment: PerformBlock methods should be used for any queue-based context.

Comment: Correct, except when setting properties

Comment: That is incorrect. The managed object and its properties are owned by the context. Accessing properties is not thread safe and should be done through the perform block methods.

Comment: Check the documentation.

Comment: I am well aware of the `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation that states: "Setter methods on queue-based managed object contexts are thread-safe." This is referring to property methods on *the managed object context*, not the managed objects it owns. Managed object properties are *not* thread safe.